Name of a Teen Sci Fi about convicts from different planets being dumped on a planet together
I am trying to remember the name of a teen Sci Fi about convicts from different planets being dumped on a planet together I remember one of them was thought to be fat by the rest but was just incredibly muscular. He may have been the main character. There was one that was pale-skinned and lanky and he wanted to kill the main character. I remember flying snake-like creatures with beaks as well

Is this a book? If so, in roughly which year did you read it?

The Fatal Shore by Robert Hughes. Oh you mean science fiction ...

Welcome to SF&F SE by the way : )

This sounds like theColesec Trilogy from the 1980s by Douglas Hill.  In particular the first book Exiles of ColSeec  and then the Caves of Klydor which is the second.
Parts that seem to match:
I am trying to remember the name of a teen Sci Fi

Match.  Teen/YA audience

about convicts from different planets

Partial match. 12 youthful convicts, but I believe all from Earth.

being dumped on a planet

Match. Dumped on Klydor planet

together I remember one of them was thought to be fat by the rest but was just incredibly muscular. He may have been the main character.

Match.  Cord McKay a Scots highlander. Stocky and thought to be fat. But then during a combat match takes off his shirt and they see just how incredibly muscular he is.

There was one that was pale-skinned and lanky and he wanted to kill the main character.

Match.  One of the exiles is actually an ex-ColSec agent/soldier.  Thin, wiry, combat trained. He is the one Cord fights.

I remember flying snake-like creatures with beaks as well

Possible match?  Please see cover pic listed below. Has snake like creature with tentacles/beaks.


